# Is the fiber product of two connected complex varieties over a connected base connected?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

If $X,Y,Z$ are connected varieties over $\mathbb{C}$, with morphisms $X\rightarrow Z, Y\rightarrow Z$, is it true that the fiber product $X\times _Z Y$ is connected?

The statement is true for $S=Spec(\mathbb{C})$, but I can't see it for general $S$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try $X,Y,Z$ all equal to $\mathbb{C}^*$ and the morphisms $z\mapsto z^2$.

Comment: @Mohan : Thank you for your answer. If I understand correctly, the underlying set of $\mathbb{C}^*\times_{\mathbb{C}^*} \mathbb{C}^*$ under the squaring map is $\{(x,x): x\neq 0 \}\sqcup \{(x,-x):x\neq 0\}$, am I correct?

Comment: @Mohan : I am actually interested in projective varieties. Would the answer be positive if we had all the varieties projective?

Comment: Whenever $X \to Y$ is a finite étale Galois cover of degree $d > 1$, the fibre product $X \times_Y X$ splits up as a disjoint union of $d$ sheets. This can happen for smooth projective varieties as well, e.g. the multiplication by $n$ map $E \to E$ on an elliptic curve (say $n$ invertible in $k$).

Comment: In light of the above comments, it may be more interesting to ask: if $Z$ is connected and $X\to Z$ and $Y\to Z$ have *connected fibers* is the fiber product connected?

Comment: @cgodfrey : That's a great point, and in fact, the maps I would like to consider DO have connected fibers. Do you have ideas about this case? That would be of great help.

Comment: This is ok when $X \to Z$ (resp. $Y \to Z$) is proper with geometrically connected fibres. Indeed, apply Tag [0377](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0377) to the proper map $X \times_Z Y \to Y$ (resp. $X \times_Z Y \to X$), which is a topological quotient since it is proper. (A similar argument can be made if you replace 'proper' by 'universally open', e.g. flat of finite presentation.)

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn : Than you so much for the reference!

Comment: @yojusmath: It is better to ask this in a separate question.